# Stopwatch App restarting from beginning when i press play button after pause button

Tags: ios, swift

The below link is my code for StopWatch app. I have done everything is perfect. But when i press on PAUSE button timer is stopping, to restart again I am going to click START button. But at that time timer runs from starting not from where the pause button stops. 
Please advice me to resolve this issue.
import UIKit

```
@IBAction func Play(sender: AnyObject) {

    timer = NSTimer.scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval(0.01, target: self, selector: Selector("increment"), userInfo: nil, repeats: true)
    startTime = NSDate.timeIntervalSinceReferenceDate()

   }

@IBAction func Pause(sender: AnyObject) {
   timer.invalidate()


}

@IBAction func Stop(sender: AnyObject) {

    timer.invalidate()
    time = 0

    resultLabel.text = "\(0):\(0):\(0):\(0)"

}
```

Comment: Please include the code in the question.

Comment: Ugh maybe it's because your reseting the time when you hit play?

Answer (score 1):

To Start:

```
timer = NSTimer.scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval(1.0, target: self, selector: Selector("updateView"), userInfo: nil, repeats: true)
```

To Resume:

```
timer = NSTimer.scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval(1.0, target: self, selector: Selector("updateView"), userInfo: nil, repeats: true)
```

To Pause:

```
timer.invalidate
```

Answer (score 0):

You should only be calling

```
startTime = NSDate.timeIntervalSinceReferenceDate()
```

When you start it originally. If you call that when you resume you will override the start time and it will be as if you are starting over.